# iPhone: Social media integration

Tags: iphone, social-media

I am developing iPhone app where I need to provide integration with different social media like FaceBook, Twitter, Google etc. I have seen couple of iPhone applications that allow people to login using their existing FB or Twitter accounts and allow to post comments, like/unlike, follow people etc. I want to implement something similar but not sure where to start with. Could anyone please suggest me right direction? Any documentation and sample code would be great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/ has just about all the info you might need.
Further also look in Apples library as it contains sample code and extensive information about most topics.

Comment: Thanks. [This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) link is really good. I think [this](http://dev.twitter.com/) should be for twitter. For now its good for me to start.

Answer (score 0):

@AppleDeveloper, check out Socialize; this is exactly the problem we're working to solve: http://www.GetSocialize.com.  Full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

The problem with just putting Facebook into your app is that your download base of users aren't all friends on Facebook.  So any sharing in the app using Facebook will only go out to that user's friends.

Socialize lets all users of the app see the social actions other users of the app take, in addition to allowing those social actions to be shared on Facebook (and soon Twitter & Google+ as well).  Then we give you a reporting dashboard so you can see the effect of all the social actions on downloads & user engagement: http://go.GetSocialize.com/dashboard

Let me know if this is the type of thing you're looking for.

DROdio

Comment: Thanks. I am going to check it out. Is it all free? Does it work with my database?

Comment: It seems it works only at whole App level. I mean user can comment on App, like, share etc but my requirements were much more. We allow users to do comment with photos, share photos, like, email, comment on other user's comment, follow, block, message, yearly/monthly/weekly/daily top users list, and much more which is fully integrated with our back-end database. I have already implemented my own solution and about to go live.

Comment: Yeah Socialize has a free level, then other tiers for the analytics data (pricing details at http://go.GetSocialize.com/pricing).  Regardless, good luck! - DROdio